# Value Error: Couldn't Convert String to Float

Tags: python, pandas

I have two input spreadsheets.

Sheet 1 has 7 columns and 3 rows

```
     / FID  / Total       / A1          / B1  /     A2      / B2 
   1 / 1   / 0.720168405 / 0.635589112 / XXX / 0.031112358 / YYY
   1 / 2  / 0.760438562 / 0.328168557 / YYY / 0.311172576 / ZZZ
```

Sheet 2 has 2 columns and 4 rows

```
       /  0
  XXX  /  0.55
  YYY  / 0.52
  ZZZ  / 0.35
```

This is the code:

```
import pandas as pd

df = pd.read_excel("C:/Users/Sheet1.xls")

df2 = pd.read_excel("C:/Users/Sheet2.xlsx")

dictionary = df2.to_dict(orient='dict')

b = df.filter(like ='A').values
c = df.filter(like ='B').replace(dictionary[0]).astype(float).values

df['AA'] = ((c * b).sum(axis =1))

df['BB'] = df.AA / df.Total

def custom_round(x, base=5):
    return base * round(float(x)/base)

df['C'] = df['BB'].apply(lambda x: custom_round(x, base=.05))
df['C'] = "X = " + df['C'].apply(lambda s: '{:,.2f}'.format(s))

df.to_excel("C:/Users/Results.xlsx")

print(df)
```

---

I have got error message: Value Error Couldn't Convert String to Float: XXX

```
ValueError                                Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-1-f42c7cb99da5> in <module>()
      8 
      9 b = df.filter(like ='A').values
---> 10 c = df.filter(like ='B').replace(dictionary[0]).astype(float).values
     11 
     12 df['AA'] = ((c * b).sum(axis =1))

C:\ProgramData\Anaconda2\lib\site-packages\pandas\core\generic.pyc in astype(self, dtype, copy, errors, **kwargs)
   5689             # else, only a single dtype is given
   5690             new_data = self._data.astype(dtype=dtype, copy=copy, errors=errors,
-> 5691                                          **kwargs)
   5692             return self._constructor(new_data).__finalize__(self)
   5693 

C:\ProgramData\Anaconda2\lib\site-packages\pandas\core\internals\managers.pyc in astype(self, dtype, **kwargs)
    529 
    530     def astype(self, dtype, **kwargs):
--> 531         return self.apply('astype', dtype=dtype, **kwargs)
    532 
    533     def convert(self, **kwargs):

C:\ProgramData\Anaconda2\lib\site-packages\pandas\core\internals\managers.pyc in apply(self, f, axes, filter, do_integrity_check, consolidate, **kwargs)
    393                                             copy=align_copy)
    394 
--> 395             applied = getattr(b, f)(**kwargs)
    396             result_blocks = _extend_blocks(applied, result_blocks)
    397 

C:\ProgramData\Anaconda2\lib\site-packages\pandas\core\internals\blocks.pyc in astype(self, dtype, copy, errors, values, **kwargs)
    532     def astype(self, dtype, copy=False, errors='raise', values=None, **kwargs):
    533         return self._astype(dtype, copy=copy, errors=errors, values=values,
--> 534                             **kwargs)
    535 
    536     def _astype(self, dtype, copy=False, errors='raise', values=None,

C:\ProgramData\Anaconda2\lib\site-packages\pandas\core\internals\blocks.pyc in _astype(self, dtype, copy, errors, values, **kwargs)
    631 
    632                     # _astype_nansafe works fine with 1-d only
--> 633                     values = astype_nansafe(values.ravel(), dtype, copy=True)
    634 
    635                 # TODO(extension)

C:\ProgramData\Anaconda2\lib\site-packages\pandas\core\dtypes\cast.pyc in astype_nansafe(arr, dtype, copy, skipna)
    700     if copy or is_object_dtype(arr) or is_object_dtype(dtype):
    701         # Explicit copy, or required since NumPy can't view from / to object.
--> 702         return arr.astype(dtype, copy=True)
    703 
    704     return arr.view(dtype)

ValueError: could not convert string to float: XXX
```

Comment: Please include the full stack trace of the exception.

Comment: always put full error message (starting at word "Traceback") in question (not comment) as text (not screenshot). There are other useful information.

Comment: error should show you in which line you try to convert text to float so you should use `print()` before converting to see what you try to convert to float and you will see what text makes problem.

Comment: I think it's because you have spaces in some of your XXX/YYY/ZZZ entries, so when you attempt to replace them with dict values, some don't get converted, then you end up trying to convert the string to a float...at least that's what happened when I tried your data: `ValueError: could not convert string to float: 'ZZZ '`, I removed the spaces and your code works for me

Comment: Yes, this is exactly the error message that I have got: ValueError: could not convert string to float: XXX. But I didn't see any space in cells "XXX", "YYY", and "ZZZ" in excel as I manually entered them. I double checked by using "find and replace" to remove extra space between words, but see the message "we couldn't find anything to replace". How do you remove the spaces? Much appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I see in the 6th line of your code you are trying to replace some set in a dataframe (XXX, YYY,.. to 0.55, 0.52, ..). But you end up supplying a dictionary 
{0:55, 1:52,..} where the keys are actually array indices.

I have changed your sheet 2 header for easier indexing like

`0    /  1
  XXX  /  0.55
  YYY  / 0.52
  ZZZ  / 0.35`

and set index using existing column 0 by replacing your line 4 as,

`dictionary = df2.set_index(0)[1].to_dict()`

and your line 6 as,

`c = df.filter(like ='B').replace(dictionary).astype(float).values`

This supplied proper dictionary to replace the dataframes.

Comment: Greatly appreciated! It finally worked out. Thank you, user3369528. And thank you everyone for your input.